# How to manage check MariaDB constraints in Adminer?

Tags: mariadb, adminer

I'm using Adminer for managing my MariaDB databases.

But I can't find how to manage check constraints and I can't find it in its docs or in Google.

How do you manage check constraints in Adminer?

Comment: Looks like there was a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/adminer/bugs-and-features/836/) back in April, this year, so it is apparently not yet a feature within Adminer.

Comment: @PaulT., it's very frustrating. Thank you for your search.